# probability Case

Tags: probability

Dears I've the below probability case
There are 20 teachers in a university. Eight (8) of them specialize in algebra, 5 in district Mathematics, 4 in physics and 3 in Geography.
How many ways we have to create sets that consist of 8 teachers, two from each profession.

and I solved as below:

A=(N(A))/(NΩ() )

A=(8×5×4×3)/(20×19×18×17 )  ×4!

is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We simply choose two instructors from each profession.

There are $$\binom 82 \cdot \binom 52 \cdot \binom 42\cdot \binom 32 = \dfrac{8!\,5!\,4!\,3!}{2!6!\,2!3!\,2!2!\,2!}= 5040$$ possible subsets which include $2$ teachers from each specialty.

(Recall, $$\binom mn = \dfrac {m!}{n!(m - n)!}$$

This is not a probability problem, so division isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thank you dear 
But in case I want to create subset the contains at least 3 teachers from specific profession like distract mathematics 
Is this rule is correct (mn)=m!n!(m−n)!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU! Very quiet for a couple weeks I suspect. +1

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pick 2 algebra,2district, 2 physics and 2 geography proffesors.

There are $\binom{8}{2},\binom{5}{2},\binom{4}{2},\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick the algebra, district physics and geography proffessors respectively. So by the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $\binom{8}{2}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick the team of proffesors. This is equal to 5040.

In case you haven't seen this notation $\binom{m}{n}$ means $m$C$ n$ they are known as the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficients)